# Ember TextArea with valueBinding is causing the cursor to jump to the end of the textarea

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ember.js

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TAWmx/7/

Using an Ember.TextArea view with valueBinding, when the user types into the textarea in IE7-9 or Opera, the cursor position changes to the end of the textarea after each key press.

In the JSFiddle example, if you start to type above the word "Test", the character you type will appear and then the cursor will jump to the text of the textarea and any remaining text you type will show up at the bottom.

This means that is is extremely difficult to make changes to text within a text area that's not at the very end.

I believe this is related to the [issue with IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899047/why-does-ie-8-make-the-cursor-jump-to-the-end-of-the-textarea-for-this-js) that causes the caret position to be lost whenever the content of the text area is modified. Is there a way around this in Ember such as doing one-way databinding?

Comment: On further inspection it looks like value binding has nothing to do with it because turning off valuebinding completely doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1154) to ember.js to save and restore the cursor position to resolve this issue in the Ember.TextArea view.